# PHP regular expression subpattern behaviour

Tags: php, regex

I want to match both the src and title attributes of an image tag:

pattern:

```
<img [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+["|\'])|title=["|\']([^"|\']+)
```

target:

```
<img src="http://someurl.jpg" class="quiz_caption" title="Caption goes here!">
```

This pattern gives me one unwanted match, title="content", and the match I actually want which is the value between the quotes after the word 'title', i.e 'content'.

So, my matches are:

```
<img src="http://someurl.jpg
http://someurl.jpg
title="Caption goes here!"
Caption goes here!
```

Is there a way to avoid the third of these matches? I'm using PCRE in PHP 5.2.x

Comment: Are you using preg_match? Can you give a complete string you are testing against? Do you know the order that source and title will be in? And last but not least, do you know about regular expressions groups and how to access variables grabbed?

Comment: That regex is wrong in many ways. The first thing that pops up it the `|` in the middle - `|title` - splits the regex to two. `"title='hello'"` will be a **whole match**, even outside of an `<img>` tag. Next, `[^"|\']+` should be `[^"']+` (or `[^"\']+` if you escape the string, not the regex). Last, there are better options to parse html in php than regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I just need to get this working. I'm not a regex master and have basically adapted a regex written by someone else. Its for a very specific case where I can guarantee that src will come before title. The complete string is the img tag I have posted. And yes, I am using preg_match. My goal is just for the title to appear as a subpattern match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly what you are looking for you could try this:

```
src="(.+?)"|title="(.+?)"
```

I would also recommend you to do some playing at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which is an online regExr in flash ... it can help you improving your knowledge and also it has many pre-built expressions by the community.

Answer (score 3):

You can't parse HTML with regular expressions, unless you know you're dealing with a subset of HTML. Your regex, even if correct, would fail e.g. if any of the attributes had a `>` character.

With the DOM extension:

```
<?php
$target = <<<EOD
<img src="http://someurl.jpg" class="quiz_caption" title="Caption goes here!">
EOD;

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($target);
$img = $d->getElementsByTagName("img");

echo $img->item(0)->getAttribute("src") . "\n";
echo $img->item(0)->getAttribute("title") . "\n";
```

Comment: +1, read this if you're not convinced : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html